# How to update adb to v.39 or newer on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, adb

I'm not very familiar with Ubuntu. Right now, I'm on adb version 1.0.32, I need adb version 39 or newer. Whatever I do I seem to be stuck at v.32 . I've tried uninstalling adb with

```
sudo apt-get remove android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

and re-installing with

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

`adb version` is still showing 32. Help!

Update: I also tried

```
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip
unzip \platform-tools-latest-linux.zip
sudo cp platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb
sudo cp platform-tools/fastboot /usr/bin/fastboot
```

But after that, when I run `adb version`, I get `-bash: /usr/bin/adb: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Comment: The problem turned out to be in the 32-bit OS that I had on the machine. Once we upgraded that to a 64-bit, I was able to update the adb with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in the fact that our Raspberry Pi's were on armv71 processors. Which are 32 bit processors. And 32-bit processors are not able to run adb versions newer than 1.0.32 because those are all meant for 64-bit processors. Once we upgraded to 64-bit, I was able to update adb.

Answer (score 1):

You could update, upgrade, uninstall adb, then reinstall adb.

```
sudo apt remove android-tools-adb
sudo apt remove android-tools-fastboot
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `adb` the installed version from Ubuntu repository:

```
sudo apt purge adb
```

Create an alias:

```
alias adb='/usr/bin/adb'
alias fastboot='/usr/bin/fastboot'
```

check it:

```
adb --version
```

Then add it to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
cat <<EOF >> ~/.bashrc
alias adb='/usr/bin/adb'
alias fastboot='/usr/bin/fastboot'
EOF
```

run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```